# Weird bug when displaying image

Tags: html, css, next.js, tailwind-css

Using next.js and Tailwind, I'm trying to place a logo in the upper right corner of the viewport, which I do successfully if said logo is simply a text.

However, whenever I try to display the logo with an **img or svg** tag it simply doesn't show.

What's even weirder, is that if I keep the text ('a' tag), the logo shows underneath.

I don't know what I'm missing here.

This **works** (but I don't want the text):

```
<div className="fixed top-0 right-0 p-4">
      <a className="transition duration-200 filter drop-shadow">
        luna
      </a>
      
      <img 
        alt="logo" 
        srcset="svg/logo_white.svg"/>
</div>
```

This **doesn't work** (logo doesn't show - I only deleted the 'a' tag):

```
<div className="fixed top-0 right-0 p-4">
      <img 
        alt="logo" 
        srcset="svg/logo_white.svg"/>
</div>
```

I can't seem to wrap my head around it. Can someone enlighten me? Thank you!

Comment: Its class and not className, its src and not srcset.

Comment: @Grumpy in react it's actually `className`. And for `img` tag `srcset` works fine

Comment: Check if your `path to image file` is correct becuase I see no problem in the img tag itself.

Comment: 'className' is used in React/Next.js, but both are correct. Also the path is correct, because as I said, the image displays when it is followed with some text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this way

```
import Image from 'next/image'
<div className="fixed top-0 right-0 p-4">
     <Image src="svg/logo_white.svg" alt="logo" width="64" height="64" />
</div>
```

Comment: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving

Comment: This works! Thank you very much! Could you please elaborate in why I should use the 'Image' component instead of the classic HTML way of doing things?

Comment: Basically, this is next element instead of HTML img tag